# Floating point comparsion ignores decimal point

Tags: bash

Hi I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
atmo =`echo "-5000*l(10^-6)" | bc -l`
echo "Threshold: $atmo m"
for altitude in {70000..0..10}
do
  if [[ $altitude < $atmo ]]; then
    printf "A %.1f m\n" "$altitude"
  else
    printf "B %.1f m\n" "$altitude"
  fi
done
```

So if the `altitude` is to high (about 69077) it should go in the else branch. Now this actually works until the `altitude` is loosing one significant figure (e.g. switching from 10000 to 9990). It then starts going to the else branch until the `altitude` is then below the one tenth of `atmo`. This again happens when the altitude switches from 1000 to 990. Again it goes into the else branch until the altitude is below one hundredths of `atmo` and so on.

So it's basically:

- 70000 to 69080: else branch (correct)
- 69000 to 10000: if branch (correct)
- 9990 to 6910: else branch (**incorrect**)
- 6900 to 1000: if branch (correct)
- 990 to 700: else branch (**incorrect**)
- 690 to 100: if branch (correct)
- 90 to 70: else branch (**incorrect**)
- 60 to 0: if branch (correct)

Now the question is how can I fix this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `[[ $altitude < $atmo ]]` does a string comparison. `$atmo` is 69077, which alphbetically comes before 700 and after 100000, thus giving you the strange results.

Bash doesn't support decimals, so you can use `bc` to compare as well:

```
if (( $(bc -l <<< "$altitude < $atmo") ))
then
  printf "A"
else
  printf "B"
fi
printf " %.1f m\n" "$altitude"
```

Comment: Okay I thought bash (and not sh alone) was able to do proper floating point comparison and it worked mostly so I guessed it has to be something else. So thanks for the answer it works.